# Применение шаблона битрикса к некоторым каталогам

Tags: шаблоны, php, cms, битрикс

Привет. Делаю английскую версию сайта на Битриксе без использования многосайтовости. Тоетсь у меня основная структура для русской версии лежит в корне, а английская в /en. Применил к /en/ шаблон главной страницы английской версии, но не знаю как применить для всех остальных папок другой шаблон. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

В условиях для выбора шаблоны есть "выражение php" 
[подробнее](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=4&LESSON_ID=26)

Comment: битрикс поддерживает перевод сайта как отдельный сайт - соответственно на обычной лицензии можно сделать только перевод на один язык, а потом придется покупать еще лицензию на дополнительный сайт

Answer (score 1):

Битрикс поддерживает мультиязычность ( переводы )